# Installing fonts doesn't work

Tags: xcode, swift

I have tried a couple font's but it just won't work. The latest I tried was this one:
https://github.com/thii/FontAwesome.swift

I used this piece of code:

```
        let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.fontAwesomeOfSize(20)] as Dictionary!
        let newBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: String.fontAwesomeIconWithName(FontAwesome.ChevronLeft), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "back:")
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = newBackButton;
```

But all it shows me is this:

[image]

I dragged the swift files and the otf file in my project like it asked me to.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few steps you need to make sure you complete, to use custom fonts in your app:

1. Add fonts to your project
2. Include them in your target
3. Double check the bundle to ensure they're included
4. Add them to your plist

Seems like you're missing step 4. Open your plist and add a new row called “Fonts provided by application”. This is an array that contains all the filenames of the fonts you want to use. Make sure to match the font name with extension exactly. Naming is the tricky part - double check that everything matches. Some fonts have weird filenames.

You also need to actually set the font of your button to your FontAwesome font. Currently you're just setting the button to the string. Looks like you forgot this line:

```
let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.fontAwesomeOfSize(20)] as Dictionary!
```

Comment: Another thing to do is this. Make sure the name of the file is correct in your resource folder. When i used open sans font, for some reason it was copied as OpenSans-Regular but when i looked in finder it was just OpenSans. So just double check your typing the correct font when setting it in code. Also clean your code too. Fonts aren't tricky to use they are just tedious with the whole installing process

Comment: I did everything the way you said and I editted my piece of code in my question to how I have it now. But it still doesn't work somehow. I guess I'm doing something wrong with the code.

Comment: I editted the code in your answer to what worked for me! Thanks!